# How to add a hotspare with storcli to a LSI MegaRAID controller?

Tags: lsi, megaraid, storcli

I have a LSI MegaRAID controller.  I pulled out a failed drive and replaced it with a good one.  I didn't run any special `storcli` commands before this, I just swapped the drives.  Unsure if that was a mistake.

It shows up as `UGood`:

```
32:8    26 UGood  F 1.818 TB SATA HDD N   N  512B ST32000645NS U  -
```

I want to add it as a hotspare, but the command fails:

```
# ./storcli64 /c0/e32/s8 add hotsparedrive
Controller = 0
Status = Failure
Description = Add Hot Spare Failed.

Detailed Status :
===============

------------------------------------------------
Drive       Status  ErrCd ErrMsg                
------------------------------------------------
/c0/e32/s8 Failure   255 Device state invalid. 
------------------------------------------------
```

What should I set the drive state to first?  Should I also initialize the drive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the drive was labeled *foreign*, probably because it had once belonged to another RAID system.  I don't know the history of the drive, so that's plausible.

The letter **F** in the status indicates that it's foreign.

You can clear the foreign config with:
storcli /c0/fall delete

Answer (score 1):

```
./storcli /c0/e32/s8 set good force
./storcli /c0/e32/s8 add hotsparedrive
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea how it works with storcli64, but I just had to replace a raid1 failed drive (slot 0) with megacli64 :

```
 ./MegaCli64 -PDMakeGood -PhysDrv \[252:0\] -aALL
 ./MegaCli64 -CfgForeign -Clear -aALL
 ./MegaCli64 -PdReplaceMissing -PhysDrv[252:0] -Array0 -row0 -a0
 ./MegaCli64 -PDRbld -Start -PhysDrv[252:0] -a0
 ./MegaCli64 -PDRbld -ShowProg -PhysDrv[252:0] -a0
```